# what do you understand by printf () function in respect of function overloading?

Tags: c, function, overloading

I know that when a class has multiple functions with the same name and different parameter list it is called function overloading.

But in case of `printf()` function, whenever we want to print values of different data types by using format specifiers like this as given below

```
printf("%c%d%f",a,b,c);
```

can we say it is function overloading?

Comment: C does not have function overloading. I think you are asking about variable arguments. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351792/does-c-support-overloading

Comment: How printf handles arguments : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433295/how-does-printf-handle-its-arguments. Its a variadic function.

Answer (score 1):

No. Its not function overloading. C doesn't support overloading. `printf` is [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) which accepts a variable number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism of function overloading in C.

With function overloading, you have different functions with the same name but with different signatures. `printf` is a variadic function (it accepts a variable number of arguments) and it has a single signature:

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```