# How does the compiler know the prototype of printf( ) in this code?

Tags: c, printf

In the following code,

```
#include<conio.h>
clrscr();
gotoxy(10, 20);
ch= getch(a);
```

we can see that the library functions have  been called without defining their prototype, the three library functions: `clrscr() gotoxy(int int)` and `getch()` have their prototypes defined in the conio.h header file which appear in the header file itself like this,

```
void clrscr();
void gotoxy(int int);
int getch();
```

But in the following code how does the compiler know the prototype of the `printf()` function? Since the code gets executed without any errors, although in the first `printf()` the last int format specifier prints the garbage value and in the second the value of `j` doesn't get printed at all since it has not been specified.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i=10, int j=20;
printf("%d%d%d",i,j);
printf("%d",i,j);
```

How does the header file stdio.h describe the scenarios when the format specifiers are float or char variables for the `printf()` functions?

Comment: `...`. Note that good compilers will find the error anyway.

Comment: This is a thing called a _variadic_ function.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433295/how-does-printf-handle-its-arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does printf handle its arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433295/how-does-printf-handle-its-arguments)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows the prototype because it's declared in `<stdio.h>`, which you're including.

`<stdio.h>` does not describe the format specifiers. It simply says

```
int printf(const char *, ...);
```

The `...` indicates that `printf` takes a variable number of arguments (of unknown type).

---

Your first call to `printf` has undefined behavior (not enough arguments for the format string). Your second call is fine (excess arguments are simply ignored). C compilers are not required to detect format string issues like this.

Comment: Ok, what is the prototype of the printf() function in the stdio.h header file?

Comment: What do you mean? It's `const char *, ...`, as my answer says.

Comment: @AndrewGates `cont char *` is a syntax error, and so is `.....`. What source are you learning C from?

Answer (score 0):

Any predefined function like `printf` should be prototyped or declared before using, in respective header file so that while executing the program compiler can verify whether programmer uses correct format or not.

`printf()` function `prototype` is declared in `header file` called `stdio.h`.

when compiler executes first line of your code which is `#include<stdio.h>` It came to know about `printf` prototype.

`man 3 printf` says

```
 int printf(const char *format, ...);// last 3 dots specifies the variable no of arguments printf can take
```

In your code below `printf` is causing **undefined behaviour** because `printf` expects `3` arguments but you provided only `2` arguments.

```
printf("%d%d%d",i,j);
```

Comment: What's with `the` random `code formatting` in `your` answer?

Comment: I'm sorry to sound confused but, I know what you have mentioned and the only thing I was asking was that if I had a float or char constant in the code, then how would the header file define the prototype provided I missed either the format specifier or the variable declaration itself like in the example I have given?

Comment: [How do I format my post using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: @AndrewGates printf starts mapping arguments from `Right` to `Left`. If you provided `%d` and giving `double` variable then it will be a undefined behaviour otherwise it prints expected result.

Comment: @AndrewGates __if I had a float or char constant in the code, then how would the header file define the prototype__ . Only `1st argument` is fixed in `printf` which is `const char*` that means `string(double quotation)` and inside `double quotation` whatever format specifier written it maps with respective arguments. If its missing it prints some junk data.

Answer (score 0):

The stdio header always includes the same declaration of printf() which is:

```
int printf(const char *fmt, ...);
```

the declaration is always the same no matter which placehoder you put into your format string.

Normally the definition\implementation of printf iterates over each character in the fmt string and will replace each identified placeholder with the appropriate argument. The compiled code will try to use the arguments instead of the placeholders in the same order as they are specified in the source code.

Comment: So this means that if the printf() has got char/float arguments even then the prototype would stay as "int printf()" ?

Comment: @AndrewGates `int` is the `return value` of `printf`. whatever arguments `printf` takes that may be char, float or double , it always returns `integer(no of printable char)`.

Comment: @AndrewGates `int printf()` is a function declaration without a prototype. A "prototype" is the thing between `(` `)`.

Comment: @AndrewGates If you are interested in how printf manages to handle a variable number of parameters "va_start", "va_arg" and "va_end" are the functions which are used to replace each found placeholder in the format string.